# Django Rest Framework - Html renderer broken?

Tags: django, templates, django-rest-framework, renderer

i am currently trying to return one html page from my django rest framework setup:

```
@action(detail=True)
@renderer_classes((TemplateHTMLRenderer,))
def confirmation(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = self.get_object()

    print(request.accepted_renderer) -> BrowsableAPIRenderer | WHY ?

    // do some business logic

    return Response({'user': user}, template_name='confirmation.html')
```

But browser prints error:

```
Object of type 'User' is not JSON serializable
```

So my question is, why does DRF use BrowsableAPIRenderer when i specified TemplateHTMLRenderer?

Can anybody help me out?

TemplateHTMLRenderer is very poorly documented, so i had to ask this question..

Thanks and Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems the ***`renderer_classes` decorator*** is not working properly with CBV. Anyway, I found one workaround/DRF way to do it.

Override the **`get_renderers()`** method

```
class Foo(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # your code
    def get_renderers(self):
        if self.action == 'confirmation':
            return [TemplateHTMLRenderer()]
        else:
            return super().get_renderers()

    @action(detail=True)
    def confirmation(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.get_object()
        return Response({'user': user}, template_name='confirmation.html')
```